# Getting selected rows of report files from a WPF Datagrid on button click

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my first question on stackoverflow and I am entirely new to programming in C# so please bear with me. I created an application using WPF in which I displayed a list of files with .rpt extension in a datagrid. The datagrid contains the list of filenames and there is also a checkbox column in the datagrid. These files are populated in the grid dynamically from a folder browser when I click on a button. I am stuck on the part of retreiving these files for printing when I click on a second button (print, as I need to call a service to print the selected files).

This is the code snippet that I have tried until now:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class ReportFile
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string inputPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog fldDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        fldDlg.SelectedPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        DialogResult result = fldDlg.ShowDialog();
        foreach (string str in Directory.GetFiles(fldDlg.SelectedPath))
        {

            ReportFile reportFile = new ReportFile();
            reportFile.Path = str;
            reportFile.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(str);
            dataGrid1.Items.Add(reportFile);
        }
    }

    private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ReportFile drv in dataGrid1.SelectedItems.OfType<ReportFile>())
        {
            if (drv != null)
            {
                DataRow row = drv.Row;
                Title = row.ItemArray[3].ToString();
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Title.ToString());
            }
        }

        var TransactionFactory = new TransactionFactory();
        var Transaction = TransactionFactory.NewTransactionString();
        var EnvironmentValue = (string)cmbEnvironment.SelectedValue;
        var CirieEngineServiceClientFactory = new CirieEngineServiceClientFactory(EnvironmentValue);

        var CirieEngineServiceClient = CirieEngineServiceClientFactory.NewCirieEngineServiceClient();
        var Form = new Cirie.Form()
        {
            Path = string.Empty,
            Title = string.Empty
        };

        var PackageID = Convert.ToInt16(txtPackageID.SelectedText);
        var Generation = Convert.ToInt16(txtGeneration.SelectedText);
        var formList = new List<Cirie.Form>();
        var stream = CirieEngineServiceClient.PrintFormCollection
            (Transaction,
             new Collection<Cirie.Form>(formList),
             PackageID,
             Generation
             );
    }
}
```

But I am not sure if it is correct since there is an exception being thrown: Unable to cast object of type 'ReportFile' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'

I would really appreciate help on this one please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `OfType` method to cast the `SelectedItems` to `ReportFile` objects and then access any properties of the `ReportFile` class:

```
foreach (ReportFile drv in dataGrid1.SelectedItems.OfType<ReportFile>())
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: This resolved the error! thank you. I also wanted to know how I could retrieve the data and send it to the print service on the button click. Since the code that I have right now manages to display the retrieved files in a message box.

Comment: I though I have already answered how to retrieve the data? Or what data do you mean?

Comment: I edited my question and added the code behind if that better helps to understand what exactly I am looking for.

Comment: No, it doesn't. A ReportFile has a Path and a FileName. Which one are you interested in and what is Title?

Comment: I am sorry but the code is no where near perfect and that is why I am looking for help. Since I need to print out the reports by making a call to the service and the reports are in my local system then I believe I would be needing the Path. And the foreach loop is a code snippet that I looked up somewhere and it is just the Message Box with a title which displays the files from the grid since I have not yet figured out how to extract the report for printing directly with a button click rather than just displaying them.

Comment: Again, a ReportFile object has a Path and a FileName only. What exaclty is it that you want to extract? The path or the filename?

Comment: I need the path

Comment: You get it from drv.Path inside the for loop: string path = drv.Path;